# Is there a way to change Power BI interface to black/grey/dark?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to change Power BI interface to a dark theme? I don't have a old version on Power BI to revert to, and since they've released the new version the interface seems to be light only.

I have tried to look in File>Options and Settings>Settings but I can't see any options there for any themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power BI Desktop only comes with the light theme since the interface change about 6 months ago, and there is no 'dark mode' at this time. MS have stated that it is on the roadmap for Power BI Desktop, but as of Nov 2020, there is no confirmed date.

There is an [Power BI Ideas for this option](https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=6dd17d27-dd56-4784-9931-7fd06e6b410e) which you can vote for, which is in the top 5 of the voted ideas so far.